# Logging doesn't occur when a shell is called in CakePHP 2.1

Tags: shell, cakephp, logging, cron, cakephp-2.1

I am facing a strange behavior by CakePHP 2.1:

I have a method, `$this->Time->getTime();` which always logs an action, then returns true. When called from the browser, it works as expected: logs the action, then returns true.

I created a shell, `TimeShell`, in which I log another action **only** if `$this->Time->getTime();` returns true. Now, the weird thing is that the second action is logged, hence the method returned true, but the action from the method (which obviously had to run since it passed it and returned true) isn't logged.

Why isn't the first action logged when the method is called from the shell? (if it helps, the shell is run via a cron job on my server)

**EDIT**

After further testing, I found out that if I don't log the second action (the one in the shell), then the first action (in `$this->Time->getTime();`) is correctly logged. But I can't figure out why does Cake only log the last action from those which should be logged.

Moreover, it seems that only the DatabaseLogger behaves this way, FileLog logs both actions. Very weird.

Comment: Cakephp 2.1 is a beta version. perhaps not the best idea.

Comment: I know, but I've needed some of its new features. You believe this could be the problem? In the changelog there is nothing referring to shells/console/logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the answer was extremely simple: I forgot to call `$this->Log->create();` before saving the logged action, hence the second action was overwriting the first one.

This being said, I recommend checking that you have the `create();` method called if you encounter any problem with saving data (mostly when overwriting occurs). In many cases, this would be the solution.

Comment: The CakePHP team recommends that you use the static methods of the CakeLog object to do logging, rather than the legacy inherited methods since all objects do not inherit from a class that uses logger.  CakeLog::write() might work better and prevent this issue.

Comment: This is the way I logged my actions. I've solved the problem, thank you for your tip, anyway.